# Octave rasterread vs Matlab geotiffread

Tags: matlab, octave, gdal

I have some Matlab code that uses the [geotiffread function](https://it.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffread.html) (mapping toolbox). Now I would like to port this code to Octave, and to do that I have to use the [rasterread function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/function/rasterread.html) (mapping octave forge package).

The two functions are not identical: the octave function should provide access to the same information of its Matlab counterpart, but the return values are quite different (structure arrays with different size/shape, fields, ...). Is there any resource, a part from the reference of the two functions, to map geotiffread and rasterread?

Comment: you can help building a `geotiffread` wrapper around rasterread and have a look at the sourcecode. Perhaps you should also have a look at the mercurial repo, perhaps someone already has started writing such a wrapper

Comment: This may not be directly an answer to your question, but here's an answer I gave in the past which has a direct translation of a particular piece of code from Matlab to Octave from geotiffread to rasterread https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214262/4183191 Hope it helps.